# Internet Explorer says Not responding due to long running script while loading a asp and tinymce related text editor

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, internet-explorer-11, episerver

Internet Explorer says  Not responding due to long running script while loading a episerver based asp web app and tinymce related in the loading content as text editor.So how to get rid of it.Some time IE crashes.Location is when tinyMCE called to apply it to the text area.

```js
function addTinyMCE(){
$('textarea').tinymce({  
  script_url:'tiny_mce.js',
  theme:'advanced',
  mode:'none',
});
  }

var config={
  autoOpen:true,
  open:addTinyMCE //HERE IT TAKES THE NOT RESPONDING DUE TO A LONG RUNNING SCRIPT
}
```

So need to fix this issue because i need to use the editor as tinyMCE

Comment: What version of EPiServer are you running? Unsure the exact version IE11 support was added, but I think it was with version 8.0

Comment: IE 11 .EPISERVER 7.5 . In the console it displays SCRIPT2343: Stack overflow . Also it shows SCRIPT28:Out of stack space , File:tiny_mce_src.js

Answer (score 6):

[image: Enable Browser Link]

In the Visual Studio 2013 toolbar, Refresh button adjacent to Browse With:

uncheck **Enable Browser Link**

Comment: It's not clear where this option exactly is. Please edit your answer

Answer (score 0):

The TinyMCE version as configured and shipped with EPiServer 7.5 is not compatible with IE11. You will need to upgrade to EPiServer 8 for a compatible version.